# Approximate the Dirichlet function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The Dirichlet function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in [a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in [a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ is known to be nowhere continuous on its domain.

My question is, is that possible to approximate it by a sequence of continuous functions?

i.e. $\forall \epsilon > 0$, is there a continuous function g defined on $[a,b]$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)| < \epsilon \forall x \in [a,b]$?

Comment: Look into Baire classes of functions - for example class $1$ are the functions that are pointwise limits of continuous functions and there is a strong condition on the set of their points of continuity which is large in a sense

Answer (score 2):

No. A continuous function near 1 at a rational number must be above 0.5 in some open neighborhood of the rational number. That open neighborhood contains irrational numbers.

Comment: @jjagmath no, read the question more carefully. The asker is asking about $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is a continuous $g$ such that for all $x \in [a, b]$, $|f(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon$. In particular, $g$ cannot depend on $x$. Your sequence doesn't even converge pointwise to $f$. For example, $f_n(0) = 1 / 2$ for all $n$, and doesn't converge to $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully the question.

Comment: And also made a mistake in my function. In intended to use $\frac{1}{1+n x^2}$